# How to update ALIAS columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like below :

```
select <few column names>, 
       0.0 as 'first alias column name', 
       0.0 as 'second alias column name' 
into ##tempTable 
from (one query UNION second query) 
where <some conditions>
```

Now later I have to update this `##tempTables`'s these 2 ALIAS columns.

Any idea, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do little here and there in query.

Case 1:-

```
Select <few column names>, 
           0.0 as 'firstAliasColumnName', 
           0.0 as 'secondAliasColumnName' 
    into ##tempTable from (one query UNION second query) where <some conditions>
```

After doing this, If we run

```
select 'firstAliasColumnName' from ##tempTable.
```

I am getting...

```
--------------------

<ListOfValues>
```

And for update, I had to write

```
update ##tempTable set firstAliasColumnName=.4 where <some condition>
```

and it will update my table properly.

Case 2:-

```
   Select <few column names>, 
                   1.00 as 'firstAliasColumnName', 
                   1.00 as 'secondAliasColumnName' 
            into ##tempTable from (one query UNION second query) 
             where <some conditions>
```

below update will work.

```
update ##tempTable set firstAliasColumnName=1.42 where <some condition>
```

And so on...

But Yes, there should not be any SPACES between ALIAS column names

Thanks

Jai

Answer (score 1):

I hope you didn't really have an alias with spaces in its name! But basically, you would use an `UPDATE` statement to update that temporary table - just like any other table:

```
UPDATE #tempTable
SET AliasColumn1 = somevalue,
    AliasColumn2 = someOthervalue
WHERE (some condition)
```

**Update:** the problem is this: with the `SELECT ... INTO ##tempTable` and supplying `0.0` as the values approach, your temp table gets two columns of type `NUMERIC` with a precision = 1 and scale = 1 - 1 digit total, of which 1 digit after the decimal point. Basically that's an unusable numeric values, since you cannot supply any values that will fit.....

So basically, you should **create** your temp table specifically, before using it:

```
CREATE TABLE ##tempTable 
       (list of columns, 
        AliasColumn1 DECIMAL(12,2), 
        AliasColumn2 DECIMAL(12,2)
       )
```

and now you can insert values into that table

```
INSERT INTO ##tempTable(columns......)
   SELECT  ........
```

and then you can easily also **update** that table since you now have **usable** numeric columns

Comment: Actually, I tried using ALIAS columns name without using SPACES as well. That also not working.

Comment: @Jai: **HOW** *not working*? Do you get an error --_> if so: ***WHAT*** error?

Comment: Getting error like:-Data truncation 

 More exceptions ... Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

 Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): The statement has been terminated.
          <--- ..
I am trying like update ##temptable set firstAliasNamew=2.3 and  update ##temptable set firstAliasNamew='2.3'

Comment: @Jai: well, what **datatype** are your columns in `#tempTable`, and what are you trying to update them with??

Comment: Nothing specific. If you see the query, I have written something like 0.0 only. I am not really ALIASing any existing column.

Comment: @Jai: maybe you need to explicitly create the temp table first before using it, so you can **define** what datatypes you'd like to have...

Comment: If I do that, don't you think that would not be any more tempTable!!

Comment: @marc_s, I have posted answer of my question. Please have a look. Thanks for your spontaneous replies.